# Anaconda 3 throwing error when installed in Linux Mint 19

Tags: linux-mint, anaconda3

I had a previous version of Anaconda 2 (working with Python 2.7), which I uninstalled to newly install Anaconda 3 (to work with Python 3.x).

While the previous Anaconda 2 was working fine, the newly installed Anaconda 3 throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/partha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/main_window.py", line 541, in setup
    self.post_setup(conda_data=conda_data)
  File "/home/partha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/main_window.py", line 578, in post_setup
    self.tab_home.setup(conda_data)
  File "/home/partha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/tabs/home.py", line 169, in setup
    self.set_applications(applications, packages)
  File "/home/partha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/tabs/home.py", line 204, in set_applications
    apps = self.api.process_apps(applications, prefix=self.current_prefix)
  File "/home/partha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 848, in process_apps
    app = app(config=self.config, process_api=self._process_api, conda_api=self._conda_api)
  File "/home/partha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/vscode.py", line 48, in __init__
    **kwargs
  File "/home/partha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/base.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.init()
  File "/home/partha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/base.py", line 60, in init
    SUBDIR, INST_EXT, INST_DIR = self._find_linux_install_dir()
  File "/home/partha/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/vscode.py", line 168, in _find_linux_install_dir
    if DISTRO_NAME in ['ubuntu', 'debian']:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'DISTRO_NAME' referenced before assignment
```

Any help to get started with the new installation will be much appreciated.
I am using `Linux Mint 19` with the following info:

```
...$ cat /etc/linuxmint/info
RELEASE=19
CODENAME=tara
EDITION="Xfce"
DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 19 Tara"
DESKTOP=Gnome
TOOLKIT=GTK
NEW_FEATURES_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_tara_xfce_whatsnew.php
RELEASE_NOTES_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_tara_xfce.php
USER_GUIDE_URL=help:linuxmint
GRUB_TITLE=Linux Mint 19 Xfce
...$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search showed that an issue was open about your problems few days ago [in github](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11662)

Fortunately a workaround was posted:

> Editing the file: ".../anaconda3//lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/external_apps/vscode.py"
>   By declaring the variable outside the loop.
>   Just add the line: 
>   `DISTRO_NAME = None`
>   on Line 159 and indent it in line with the if above it (Outside it)

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar experience this morning. But I was able to resolve mine by typing this into my command-line interface(CLI).

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

I hope this work for you.